# Problems parsing and printing integers with MIPS

Tags: formatting, integer, stack, mips

I'm doing a homework assignment where I need to calculate a parenthesized math problem using the runtime stack in MIPS and I've hit a bit of a snag:

I've gotten to the point where I'm trying to parse the integers out of the user supplied input.  It worked really well when it only dealt with single digits, but when I got to two digit numbers it gave me problems (I was using Syscall 4 or the print string function).  For example, I'd punch in 77 and it'd give me "H".  So I switched the syscall to 1, the print integer command and now I get insanely large numbers.  Is there anyway I can accomplish what I need to do?

My code so far.  Ignore the add and subtract methods, they haven't been implemented yet.  I feel that after I solve this problem those should be pretty easy to introduce.

```
    .data

Welcome:    .asciiz "\nCalculate a Fully Parenthesized Expression.\n"
promptExpr: .asciiz "Enter the expression: "
bufExpr:    .space  200

    .text
    .globl main

main:
    la  $a0, Welcome
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    la  $a0, promptExpr
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    li  $v0, 8
    la  $a0, bufExpr
    li  $a1, 200
    syscall

    li  $t0, 0
    subu    $sp, $sp, 4
    sw  $t0, ($sp)
    li  $t1, 0

Loop:   lb  $t0, bufExpr($t1)
    beq $t0, 10, endProg
    beq $t0, 45, negCheck
    bgt $t0, 47, num
    beq $t0, 41, calc
    bne $t0, 32, push
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1
    j   Loop

endProg:
    li  $t1, 0
    la  $a0, ($sp)
    li  $v0, 1
    syscall

    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

num:    
    move    $t2, $t0
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1
    lb  $t0, bufExpr($t1)
    bgt $t0, 47, collect
    subu    $sp, $sp, 4
    sw  $t2, ($sp)
    addu    $t1, $t1, 1
    j   Loop

collect:
    # collects the entire integer by multiplying the current amount by ten
    # and adding the next digit.
    li  $t7, 10
    mul $t2, $t2, $t7
    addu    $t2, $t2, $t0
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1
    lb  $t0, bufExpr($t1)
    bgt $t0, 47, collect
    subu    $sp, $sp, 4
    sw  $t2, ($sp)
    j   Loop

push:
    subu    $sp, $sp, 4
    sw  $t0, ($sp)
    addu    $t1, $t1, 1
    j   Loop

negCheck:

calc:
    lw  $t4, ($sp)
    addu    $sp, $sp, 4
    lw  $t5, ($sp)
    addu    $sp, $sp, 4
    move    $t0, $t4
    beq $t5, 40, push
    lw  $t6, ($sp)
    addu    $sp, $sp, 4
    lw  $t7, ($sp)
    addu    $sp, $sp, 4
    beq $t5, 43, addMath
    beq $t5, 45, subMath

addMath:

subMath:
```

Sorry if my code is kind of messy, MIPS gives me a headache.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract `'0'` (decimal `48`) in your `num`/`collect` routine to convert the characters from your input string into values in the range `0..9`.

Otherwise if you enter the string `12` at the prompt you'll get `'1' * 10 + '2'`, i.e. `49 * 10 + 50` (= 540).